# How to find if there is an expander in my controller

Tags: dell-perc, raid-controller, h700

I have 2U PowerEdge R510 with PERC H700 Integrated and 8 installed disks, can someone tell me how to find if my disks are using the expander in the backplane or there are all directly attached to the controller. I am experiencing strange 500~550Mbytes/s read+write limitation with my 8 SSD disks in raid5. I know the controller has 2x4 internal connectors, so 8 disks can be direct attached, each with 6G supported? I know the server has 12 harddisk bays and I can use them all.

Comment: You might wish to contact Dell and ask about this as they would be the most technically qualified.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two [SFF-8087 ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SFF_8087.jpg) on your controller, each one of those ports is a 4-lane SAS port. Natively, that would only be able to address *EIGHT* disks. With the use of an expander on the backplane, you can accommodate a greater number of disks.

So if your backplane can fit *TWELVE* drives, there's an expander on it. Also, look at the server. See if there's only one cable connecting the controller to the backplane.

-- Edit --

The [Dell R510 contains a dual-ported SAS expander](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails?driverId=4XG1T) on the drive backplane. You're running into oversubscription issues on the SAS link. In addition, most RAID controllers of that level have diminishing returns at SSD quantities above 6 devices.